# Can after "the more...the more..." be a noun, not a noun phrase?

Tags: phrase-usage, translation, comparative, noun-phrases

Google Translate gives me this sentence:

> He himself felt helpless in communicating, as **the more he said the wrong way**.

It's not "the more wrong it is", it's just plainly "the wrong way". But since the former is just a noun phrase, grammatically can it be trimmed to a single noun? Is this the wrong way or not?

Comment: Google Translate frequently returns incorrect English.  You should only rely on it to get a *rough idea* of how to say something in another language, as most of the time you have to clean up the grammar and phrasing.

Comment: @Andrew sorry, I've just updated my question

Comment: What's this "in theory" stuff? **the more he said** is not a NP and neither is **the wrong way it is** [sic]

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I didn't aware that it even doesn't have the second "more"...

Comment: I wonder why would this question be not useful. For lacking of research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, Google Translate does not reliably produce correct English sentences.  It should only be used to get a *rough idea* of how to translate something from another language, which you then have to clean up.

Anyway, to answer your question.  Yes, it is *possible* to use the "more X more Y" structure with simple nouns, *however* this will be considered *artificial*, not standard English.  For example, imagine an advertisement for ice cream:

> All moms know: the more **Watson's Ice Cream**, the more **happy children**.

Of course *proper* English would phrase it:

> All moms know that the more **Watson's Ice Cream they have**, the more **happy their children will be**.

But the abbreviated style is appropriate for things like advertising or pithy statements.  For example, when I teach a class that involves physical movements which are best learned through repetition (like dancing), and a student is talking about how they don't get it, I like to respond:

> Your body has to understand it before your mind can.  **Less talk more do**!

Removing all the surrounding grammar makes it more of an *authoritative statement*, as if I am expressing fact rather than opinion.  Again, it's artificial, so it would not sound right out of context.

Comment: Is it always artificial though? What if I said "The more tadpoles populate the pond, the more frogs there will be by the end of summer." I don't think that's artificial or unnatural?

Comment: @Element115 I'm not sure what you're asking?  In my answer I say that that is proper English grammar.  What I call "artificial" is something like *the more tadpoles the more frogs* or even just *more tadpoles; more frogs.*  Both are acceptable in the right context.

Comment: Oh. That makes more sense. I wasn't quite sure why you meant by artificial and I was trying to clarify. Thanks for making that clearer.

Comment: I think that using Google Translate for a rough idea can often lead you down the wrong path, so even after you've spent time trying to polish its output, you end up with an inferior result.

Comment: @snailplane in my surprise Google Translate does a good job of giving natural phrase that native speakers might use. Of course you still have to stay aware of the output, but as a translator myself I see a potential of it.

Comment: Is there any idiom for "the more he said the more wrong it is"?

Comment: @Ooker  Google translate improves with each user edit.  Some common phrases will be perfect English.  The problem is that it's not reliable, and unless you're already good in English you may not know which translations are weird.

Comment: (just add a point, not arguing) I agree that you should good enough to rely on Google Translate, but once you develop a sense to detect the unnatural phrase, then its *suggestions* can help you to find natural ones. **This does not mean trying to polish the whole output thought, you still have to translate the article by yourself.**